# New files and directories don't have same permission using setfacl

Tags: linux

I created a directory called test and use setfacl to set the permissions.  I want to create directories and files in directory test with 770 permissions.  However, when I created new directories, the directories have permission 770, but new files with permission 660.  Please see the following:

```
[root@Linux-dev-fs-1 DataRaid]# setfacl -R -d -m u::rwx test
[root@Linux-dev-fs-1 DataRaid]# setfacl -R -d -m g::rwx test
[root@Linux-dev-fs-1 DataRaid]# setfacl -R -m u::rwx test
[root@Linux-dev-fs-1 DataRaid]# setfacl -R -m g::rwx test
[root@Linux-dev-fs-1 DataRaid]# setfacl -R -m m::rwx test
[root@Linux-dev-fs-1 DataRaid]# getfacl test
# file: test
# owner: edistest
# group: edistest
user::rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---


[edistest@Linux-dev-fs-1 test]$ mkdir testdir
[edistest@Linux-dev-fs-1 test]$ ls -ls
total 4
4 drwxrwx---+ 2 edistest edistest 4096 Aug  6 16:55 testdir
[edistest@Linux-dev-fs-1 test]$ touch testfile.txt
[edistest@Linux-dev-fs-1 test]$ ls -ls
total 4
4 drwxrwx---+ 2 edistest edistest 4096 Aug  6 16:55 testdir
0 -rw-rw----+ 1 edistest edistest    0 Aug  6 16:55 testfile.txt

[edistest@Linux-dev-fs-1 test]$ getfacl *
# file: testdir
# owner: edistest
# group: edistest
user::rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---

# file: testfile.txt
# owner: edistest
# group: edistest
user::rw-
group::rwx                      #effective:rw-
mask::rw-
other::---
```

How can I set the permission using setfacl in order to create new files and directories with permission 770?

thanks!

Olivia

Answer (score 0):

I see your directory *is* getting created with 770 mode.  But an ordinary file will not be created with 770 mode because execute permission is not useful for files unless it is explicitly set by the application. In other words, `touch` creates files without execute permission because it makes no sense for it to create files with execute permission.  You can convince yourself of this by going to your ordinary home directory, checking your `umask` (probably `022`, clear group and other write permission), doing a `getfacl` on the directory and confirming it's `user::rwx`, then touching a file. It will not be created with execute permission, either. Execute permission on files must be explicitly set.